# Pentaho: How to use dynamic parameters in "Merge Rows diff" step in part Values to compare

Tags: javascript, pentaho, pentaho-spoon

I  am new at pentaho, I am using a step „Merge rows (diff)“ and compare two tables. Problem ist that I dont know the key and value fields to compare of my origin tables, I can only read them in „Javascript“-step. Do you know any variants how to use such parameters in „Merge rows (diff)“-Step? Especially I am interested in „Values to compare“, because I need two compare all columns in these two tables and the structure of the tables (for example column names) can change in database any time, so I will have always different number of fields in „value to compare“.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: It's very hard to tell what you're asking for, but take a look at metadata injection. It may also be that this step isnt suitable in your case.  You can however use every column as a key if you need to do that?

Comment: Metadata injection does not work for this step. Yes, I can use every column, but Problem is that this step does not reaad variables or Parameters.

Comment: There are other ways to do metadata injection - it can be achieved via the API. Would you consider that?

Comment: FYI merge join does support metadata injection from 7.0 and you can download a preview from the ci server or build it from source.

Comment: Can you tell me if it is modified javascript transformation from where you are getting the data?